# Team Foundation Server Upgrade Migrate Backlog Items

Tags: tfs, migration, backlog

We recently upgraded Team Foundation Server to a new version.

I'm looking for information on how to best export all backlog items in bulk and import in similar fashion to the new server instance.

In other words, the old instance is alive and contains all our work items, but the new instance is blank and contains nothing.

Comment: Why not migrate your team project collection databases?

Comment: Thanks for your comment Daniel. My question is how you do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you upgrade your old TFS to a new version or set up a new TFS?

Upgrade is a full data transfer, if you perform an upgrade, all data should shown as before. You need to go through article [Upgrade your deployment to the latest version of TFS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/tfs-server/upgrade/get-started) before doing upgrade. And follow the steps in article [Upgrade scenario walkthrough for Team Foundation Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/tfs-server/upgrade/walkthrough) to upgrade your TFS. Summarize the steps here:

> 1. **Prepare your environment**. The first step is to check the [system requirements](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/tfs-server/requirements) for TFS 2018. Upgrade SQL Server is
>      necessary for your scenario. Including SQL Server, you also need to check other system
>      requirements and prepare the environment.
> 2. **Expect the best, prepare for the worst**. You must have a complete and consistent set of [database backups](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/tfs-server/admin/backup/config-backup-sched-plan) in case something
>      goes wrong.
> 3. **Do the upgrade**. Once the preparation is done, you'll need to install the new version of TFS to get new binaries, and then run
>      through the upgrade wizard to upgrade your databases.
> 4. **Configure new features**. Depending on what version you upgraded from, you may need to [configure each team project](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/work/customize/configure-features-after-upgrade) to gain access
>      to some of the new features made available.

Comment: Sorry, it was not possible to upgrade the existing. I had to work with a new instance already in use by other teams. And so I need to migrate data to that instance. Sorry for any confusion.

Comment: So, what you need is migrating work items between TFS.  1. If you don't need the history of the work items, then use Excel to export work items from one account and import them to another account will be an option. This option will work for most work items.

Check: https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/work/office/bulk-add-modify-work-items-excel. 2. Another option will be using a 3rd part tool, like OpsHub. Check: http://www.opshub.com/products/opshub-visual-studio-migration-utility/